# Native crash reports contains offsetted addresses

Tags: android, android-ndk, crash-reports, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I have integrated Huawei Crash Service as per [documentation](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-crash-report), and I am able to see NDK crashes in web console. However, the addresses in reports are offsetted by 4, so when I want to symbolicate crash, I get wrong result.

For example, in logcat I can see

```
2020-12-10 15:23:51.981 5914-5914/? D/formatEventInfo: statck
    #00 pc 00c57c10 /data/app/package-name-w5yGIc9ek_yTyk1ARvNP-w==/lib/arm64/libName.so(std::set_unexpected(void (*)())) [arm64-v8a::]
    #01 pc 00c57d88 /data/app/package-name-w5yGIc9ek_yTyk1ARvNP-w==/lib/arm64/libName.so(unknow) [arm64-v8a::]
    #02 pc 00c54b54 /data/app/package-name-w5yGIc9ek_yTyk1ARvNP-w==/lib/arm64/libName.so(unknow) [arm64-v8a::]
    #03 pc 00c5425c /data/app/package-name-w5yGIc9ek_yTyk1ARvNP-w==/lib/arm64/libName.so(__cxa_get_exception_ptr) [arm64-v8a::]
    #04 pc 00c541dc /data/app/package-name-w5yGIc9ek_yTyk1ARvNP-w==/lib/arm64/libName.so(unknow) [arm64-v8a::]
```

and that addresses appear in web console, while valid logcat crash stack trace is

```
    --------- beginning of crash
2020-12-10 15:23:52.067 6246-6246/? I/crash_dump64: obtaining output fd from tombstoned, type: kDebuggerdTombstone
2020-12-10 15:23:52.068 871-871/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: received crash request for pid 5914
2020-12-10 15:23:52.069 6246-6246/? I/crash_dump64: performing dump of process 5914 (target tid = 5914)
2020-12-10 15:23:52.099 6246-6246/? A/DEBUG: pid: 5914, tid: 5914, name: o.a.b  >>> package-name <<<
2020-12-10 15:23:52.104 6246-6246/? A/DEBUG:       #01 pc 0000000000c57c0c  /data/app/package-name-w5yGIc9ek_yTyk1ARvNP-w==/lib/arm64/libName.so
2020-12-10 15:23:52.104 6246-6246/? A/DEBUG:       #02 pc 0000000000c57d84  /data/app/package-name-w5yGIc9ek_yTyk1ARvNP-w==/lib/arm64/libName.so
2020-12-10 15:23:52.104 6246-6246/? A/DEBUG:       #03 pc 0000000000c54b50  /data/app/package-name-w5yGIc9ek_yTyk1ARvNP-w==/lib/arm64/libName.so
2020-12-10 15:23:52.104 6246-6246/? A/DEBUG:       #04 pc 0000000000c54258  /data/app/package-name-w5yGIc9ek_yTyk1ARvNP-w==/lib/arm64/libName.so
2020-12-10 15:23:52.104 6246-6246/? A/DEBUG:       #05 pc 0000000000c541d8  /data/app/package-name-w5yGIc9ek_yTyk1ARvNP-w==/lib/arm64/libName.so (__cxa_throw+120)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The Crash Report you got is correct. Line numbers (00c57c10, 00c57c0c, etc) do not need to be exactly matched. Because an address segment is a range, for example, your 00c57c10 and the c57c0c are may in the same address of your file. If you upload the native symbol file, you may get a readable crash report.

Here you can see an example: [Obtaining an NDK Crash Report](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-crash-report-0000001054980565)

---

It seems you lost your uuid because of some mistakes of your files: [arm64-v8a::];[arm64-v8a::]... They should be with uuid.

[Documentation of the AppGallery Connect Crash service](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-crash-introduction-0000001055732708?ha_source=hms1)

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the case for me as I get different line numbers (in fact, different functions) in my source code when I symbolicate both crash logs. Why would reported crash log addresses be different from those in logcat, in the first place?

Comment: @sruzic Yes, **after parsing** the different numbers (00c57c10, 00c57d88), you will get the same crash report with the same line numbers of the file (...native.crash.creat,cpp:14).

Comment: You didn't understand me. When I symbolicate first crash log (`#00 pc 00c57c10, #01 pc 00c57d88, ...`) I get one (**wrong**) set of line numbers, and when I symbolicate second crash log (`#01 pc 0000000000c57c0c, #02 pc 0000000000c57d84, ...`) I get another (**correct** - because I know where I've thrown an exception on purpose just to test NDK crash report) set of line numbers.

Comment: My zipped native symbol file is larger than 5MB so I cannot upload it.

Comment: @sruzic OK, but it seems you put the two reports in reverse order. The second crash report is from Huawei Crash Service.

Comment: No, it is not. First report (`#00 pc 00c57c10, #01 pc 00c57d88, ...`) appears in Huawei AppGallery web console, so I suppose it is from Huawei Crash Service. Second report (`#01 pc 0000000000c57c0c, #02 pc 0000000000c57d84, ...`) is standard Android log when crash occurs, and it (second one) is visible even if I do not add `agconnect-crash-native` dependency.

Comment: @sruzic I see. Could you please upload the native symbol file to AppGallery Connect? The operation personnel will get back to you asap.